# R: Cohen's d for group sizes >2, using glm

Tags: r, package

Is there a package that will calculate Cohen's d from a glm formula for all groups? I have 4 independent variables with group sizes of 2, 5, 6, and 17.

The most common packages, `compute.es`, `effsize` and so forth do not do a Cohen's d from a glm formula or for group sizes more than 2.

Thanks!

Comment: Group sizes meaning the number of levels within each group (Male-Female=2).

Comment: I used Cohen's d to show the effect size for each difference within a particular group. And then along with the r-squared value for the model, I show the partial eta-squared to show how the variation is broken up between IV's.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at the cohen's d formula:

[image: cohen's d formula]

Cohen's d takes 2 means and normalises them with the pooled standard deviation.
It can only take 2 groups.

> ... do not do a Cohen's d from a glm formula or for group sizes more than 2.

Cohen's d is calculated for 2 groups independent of their size and in R  only takes numeric vectors as input, not formulas. Maybe you got confused by `effsize`'s formula interface:

```
require(effsize)
cohen.d(d ~ f)
```

This is not a GLM formula but a mapping of the numbers in `d` to a factor in `f`.

You would probably have to compute all pairwise cohen d's, if cohen d's are what you want. I doubt it because giving all pairwise cohen d's is not condensing your results much. Take a look at the following link, [with effect size measures for GLMs](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_glm_sect032.htm), to see whether you find anything that suits your needs.

Comment: I am pretty sure I want a Cohen's d. From an ANOVA I know there are statistical differences between, say grades(A,B,C,D/F). I then proceed with a multiple comparison test, say Tukey's, to see where the differences actually occur. Tukey's test tells me there are multiple statistically significant differences, I then need to find an effect size to really understand how big those differences are--this is what Cohen's d will tell me.

Comment: Ok, then you will have to do all pairwise combinations of cohen's d or use etta squared. Cohen's d will not work with more than 2 sets, so unfortunately you will have to make all combinations.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [this article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3840331/), the author states: "_Eta squared η2 (part of the r family of effect sizes, and an extension of r2 that can be used for more than two sets of observations) measures the proportion of the variation in Y that is associated with membership of the different groups defined by X_"

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to get Cohen's d from a glm of multiple groups.
While searching for a possible solution, I found this method using the sigmaHat function of the car package in the documentation of the ARTool package ( https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ARTool/vignettes/art-effect-size.html)

```
library(dplyr)      #%>%
library(emmeans)    #emmeans
library(DescTools)  #EtaSq
library(car)        #sigmaHat
library(ARTool)     #art, artlm
library(ggplot2)    #ggplot, stat_..., geom_..., etc

data(InteractionTestData)
df = InteractionTestData  

#we'll be doing type 3 tests, so we want sum-to-zero contrasts
options(contrasts = c("contr.sum", "contr.poly"))
m.linear = lm(Y ~ X1*X2, data=df)

x2.contrasts = summary(pairs(emmeans(m.linear, ~ X2)))

x2.contrasts$d = x2.contrasts$estimate / sigmaHat(m.linear)
x2.contrasts
```

```
 contrast estimate    SE  df t.ratio p.value       d
 C - D     -1.9121 0.142 294 -13.428 <.0001  -1.8991
 C - E     -1.8530 0.142 294 -13.013 <.0001  -1.8403
 D - E      0.0592 0.142 294   0.415 0.9093   0.0588

Results are averaged over the levels of: X1 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates
```

For me this also worked with a glm since sigmaHat returns the estimated scale from a linear, generalized linear, nonlinear, or other model.

Can someone affirm that this is a valid approach to calculate and report Cohan's d of pairwise comparisons in a glm?